# How to redirect all requests within a wlan using ad-hoc to a specific address or hostname

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, lan, adhoc

I'm setting up an ubuntu embedded system as a "master" server which will then broadcast to clients using ad-hoc in a wlan. The purpose is for a client to access the wlan and then access a webapp on my local network.

But instead of having then going to my ip address or my hostname.local i want then to be redirected from all requests to the my hostname.local address in order for them to only access my webapp and nothing else.

Searching on the forum, I found dnsmasq although I'm not sure if this would work for me seeing as I need all requests * to be redirected.

Any ideas? Regards

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to redirect all network traffic to a single web server.

You could do this with an `iptables` rule on you gateway that is controlling you WLAN.

Taken from here: https://serverfault.com/questions/365000/how-can-i-use-iptables-to-forward-all-traffic-to-a-certain-website

To redirect traffic :`/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s [source network/mask] -p all -j DNAT --to-destination [your webserver]`

You will also have to rewrite the source address to remain as you client connection and not the gateway.

To rewrite the source: `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`